# Where can I buy a new drop-in Bobbin case electric contact spring?

Tags: sewing-machine

On removing the drop-in bobbin case I broke 'the spring'. 'The spring' is pictured well in many articles but;

1. No explanation of what the 'electrical contact' spring actually does. (Other than a guide to inserting the bobbin correctly).
2. No name of the part other than 'spring'.
3. I cannot find it in the parts manual and wonder if anyone can tell me how I could find more details about it, so that I can order this. Sources would also be welcome.

(My machine is 2 weeks old and has produced nothing but birds nests, 2 broken and 1 bent needle!)

[image]

Comment: Welcome! It’s probably not a good idea to post your e-mail: All trustworthy users will use the answer section to help you solve your problem. Questions about “where can I buy” are problematic (we do have an international user base and all Q/A posts should at least potentially help future readers with the same problem, too), but asking how to identify or correctly name the part is fine. The [tour] and te [help] should explain more about how the site works.

Comment: Also for any repair questions, it's a very good idea to post the make and model, and for any questions about availability to post roughly where you are (which country)

Comment: I'm quite sad that you have so much trouble with your machine. Why don't you watch some Youtube videos or read some beginner's tutorials? You don't even need to find tutorials for your specific machine, because in principle all sewing machines work the same way. If you have a basic understanding of how a sewing machine works, maybe you can find the reason for your "birds nests". Maybe the thread tension is off or the bobbin isn't inserted all the way (as it was in my case when I started sewing).

Comment: If the machine is only 2 weeks old, the problem may be due to a manufacturing defect or improper factory adjustment.  You may be able to exchange it or get it fixed under warranty (or just return it and buy another).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't find any part numbers or additional information is because that part of the machine is not considered a "user serviceable" area. As you appear to be inexperienced with sewing machines in general, **I would strongly recommend that you not attempt to repair this part yourself**. There are many sewing machine repair shops available that can do the repair for you.